# How to enable libcurl to decompress gzip data on windows?

Tags: windows, libcurl, zlib, compression

I built openssl and `zlib` and then `libcurl` with the following command:

```
nmake -f Makefile.vc6 CFG=release-dll-ssl-dll-zlib-dll
```

In the output I could see that `zlib` is enabled during the compilation of `libcurl` classes.

But when I use the `libcurl` to fetch a compressed page with the following settings, the response is not decompressed.

```
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_ENCODING, 1L);

CURLOPT_ENCODING is defined as CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.

The libcurl version is 7.35.0. zlib version is 1.2.8 and openssl version is 1.0.1i.
```

Really appreciate if there is someone who has used `libcurl` on windows to decompress data and share your experience. Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, the response header does have content-encoding set to 'gzip'. And the same code works to decompress the data on linux platform where a prebuilt libcurl is used.

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_ENCODING is not a valid libcurl option!

You probably mean [CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING.html), but you won't need that here. Just setting [CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html) to "" is enough, but will require that libcurl was built zlib enabled to make it ask for compressed content and automatically decompress on reception.

This feature works identically on all supported platforms. It is the exact same code that runs. I would suspect your libcurl doesn't actually have it enabled if it doesn't work on a specific platform.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Yes, it was a typo. I meant CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING. I built libcurl with the CFG=release-dll-ssl-dll-zlib-dll and saw that zlib was enabled. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

I have figured out the problem. The new libcurl lib is actually enabled with zlib. The problem is in my installer which doesn't copy the new libcurl lib to the installation directory. After I replaced the lib manually, the decompression works!

Thanks!